# Is there a way to stream large data directly to S3 files instead saving locally first?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Node.js app has so big data, I don't want to save it into a file first before streaming, so my question is there a way to stream this data directly to AWS S3?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Upload` from [`@aws-sdk/lib-storage`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_lib_storage.html#upload) which may allow you to upload buffers, blobs, or streams.

For example, if you have a `stream` you can pass it to it as `Body`:

```
const { S3Client } = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
const { Upload } = require('@aws-sdk/lib-storage');

async function upload(stream, fileName, bucketName, contentType) {
    const s3Client = new S3Client({ region: "us-east-1" });
    const upload = new Upload({
        client: s3Client,
        params: {
            Bucket: bucketName,
            Key: fileName,
            Body: stream,
            ContentType: contentType,
        }
    });

    return await upload.done();
}
```